# Getting contents of a file then printing them to a separate file?

Tags: java

I have it set so that it will read a file and will split it at a colon whilst it has a next line which is here:

```
 while (s.hasNext()) {
        String line = s.nextLine();
        String[] words = line.split("\\s*:\\s*");
        //splits the file at colons
```

What I then want to do it write these lines to a different text file, I'm aware this is a basic question but I'm new to this and it would help a lot.

```
System.out.println(hteam + " " + "[" + hscore + "]" + " " + "|" + " " + ateam + " " + "[" + ascore + "]"); //output the data from the file in the format requested
```

This is the code that I am using to write it to the console but what I want to do is make it so that rather than write to the console it will write it to a seperate text file.

Comment: Dont use \\s* just split your line with ":"

Comment: Read the Java IO tutorial, and try something. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html

Comment: I've written to files before I'm just not sure how I would go about writing from one file to another

Comment: _How_ do you want to write a `String[]` to a line?

Comment: Currently I have it being output to the console but I'm not sure how I would adapt this to writing it to a file. I currently output it to the console with this:                 System.out.println(hteam + " " +  "[" + hscore + "]" +  " " + "|" + " " + ateam + " " + "[" + ascore + "]");   
                //output the data from the file in the format requested

Comment: Please add this code **to the question**. Specify the format you want to write the output in.

Comment: @robert have you tried my code given below

Comment: What is `hteam`? `hscore`? `ateam`? `ascore`? Are we supposed to guess?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to do so.

```
int count=0;
String line="";
String[] words=new String[40];
try{
  while (s.hasNext()) {
    String fileName="the-file-name"+count+".txt";
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fileName, "UTF-8");

         line =s.nextLine();
          words = line.split("\\s*:\\s*");

          for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++){
              writer.println(words[i]);
        }

        writer.close();

}

}catch(Exception e){

e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it only wrote the last line of the text file onto the new text file, any idea why this could be?

Comment: try to print the words array in your console to check if it contains all lines from your first file

Comment: use `line.split(":");` rather than `line.split("\\s*:\\s*");` if you want to split with colon

Comment: Using line.split(":");  doesn't work for the text file I have as it doesn't read them in correctly. When I put your code in to a certain part, what should I do with i? Should I make it a variable?

Comment: Should I add a declaration or surround with try/catch?

Comment: `it only wrote the last line of the text file onto the new text file`    thats because you are doing `String line = s.nextLine();` inside while loop and initialize it every time with new value.Check my edits for full code

Comment: I'm getting a duplicate variable error for these two: String line="";
String[] words=new String[40];
What should I do with them?

Comment: use try catch to handle that

Comment: What should I do with the words and line variables? They say they're a duplicate variable should I remove it through one of the places they're used?

Comment: where else you are using line and words variable ,rename them with different name .Are you using  my code above.I am assuming that you have a file you are reading lines of a file one by one then spliting them with colon and writing this line to other file after splitting the line with colon correct me if I am wrong.Ans It would be helpful if you provide the whole code

Answer (score 0):

You can first create a new file by setting its path and then write to it.

```
File file = new File("/home/user/filename.txt");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

for(i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    bw.write(content);
}
bw.close();
```

Comment: This is somewhat unhelpful; mainly because it does not close the resource in a `try with resources` or even a `finally`. You also need to print linebreaks, you could use a `PrintWriter` and call `println`.